# How do you make the tkinter text widget recognise lines in the index?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on highlighting chosen parts of a text green in a text widget in Tkinter.

To my understanding, on Tkinter the index for the second line, fourth character of a text would be 2.04. For some reason, it's not recognising a new line and the decimal number keeps increasing into the hundreds so I'm struggling to highlight words once the total characters of the text exceed 99. When it does, it highlights lots of text after the chosen word in green.

I've set the max width of the text widget to 99 characters to make the index create lines but but it's still not doing anything.

For clarification, I'm trying to highlight the word 'calculates' in green with this code.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
text_window = Text(window, height=10, width=99, wrap=WORD)
text_window.insert(INSERT, sample_text)
text_window.configure(state=DISABLED)
text_window.pack()

countVar = StringVar()
pos = text_window.search("calculates", "1.0", stopindex="end", count=countVar)
end_num = float(countVar.get()) / 100
position = float(pos)
print(position)
print(end_num)
end_point = position + end_num
text_window.tag_configure("search", background="green")
text_window.tag_add("search", pos, end_point)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try using: `end_point = pos+f"+{countVar.get()}c"`. When you are dealing with indexes don't add them like `float`s. They aren't `float`s, they are 2 integers separated by a `"."`. Also you can let `tkinter` do the calculations for more info read [this](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/text.html#M18)

Comment: _"To my understanding, on Tkinter the index for the second line, fourth character of a text would be 2.04"_ - 2.4, not 2.04. 2.04 would work, but 2.08 would not since `08` is an invalid integer (leading zero causes it to be treated as octal).

Comment: Thank you so much @TheLizzard that makes complete sense, will definitely read that additional info you sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"2.04"` is not valid. It will work, but something like `"2.08"` won't since `08` is an invalid octal number. A text widget index must be string in the form of a valid integer, a period, and then another valid integer.

The text widget index also supports modifiers, so you can easily add or subtract characters. In your case it would look something like this:

```
end_point = f"{pos}+{countVar.get()}chars"
```

or

```
end_point = f"{pos}+{countVar.get()}c"
```